# Wavefunction used in Derivation of Josephson Effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, josephson-junction

In deriving the Josephson Effect, the ansatz wavefunction is given as $\sqrt{n} \exp{(i\delta)}$ which leads to the Josephson Relations. It seems that this wavefunction is used because $<\psi|\psi>$ should give the particle density. My question then, is that this ansatz wavefunction doesn't seem to be limited to superconductivity, so why can't the derivation for the Josephson relations be used to ordinary metals divided by a thin insulating layer as well? Where does the superconductivity play in the Josephson Effect?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the main point is that in some ordinary material you have no such collective behavior as in a superconductor, which allows you to describe all electrons within your material using only one coherent wavefunction.